# WooCommerce_Widget_Product_Categories widget remove category

Tags: widget, woocommerce

I used the WooCommerce Product Categories widget but i need to "remove" from the list created some category, i add the option in the widget, but have no idea where to put it in the code... can somebody help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to do this yesterday. Here is my solution.

On your functions.php add this:

```
function exclude_widget_categories($args){
    $exclude = "25"; // The IDs of the excluding categories separated by commas.
    $args["exclude"] = $exclude;
    return $args;
}


add_filter("woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args","exclude_widget_categories");
```

I adapted this snippet I found here: [Exclude category from widget category list](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/excluding-category-from-widget) to work with the woocommerce filter.